# Creating Large List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, linq, list

I have the following code:

```
var lstMusicInfo = new List<MediaFile>();
var LocalMusic = Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppSettings.Default.ComputerMusicFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsParallel().ToList<string>();
LocalMusic = (from a in LocalMusic.AsParallel()
              where a.EndsWith(".mp3") || a.EndsWith(".wma")
              select a).ToList<string>();
var DeviceMusic = adb.SyncMedia(this.dev, AppSettings.Default.ComputerMusicFolder, 1);
```

---

```
Parallel.ForEach(LocalMusic, new Action<string>(item =>
    {
        try
        {
            UltraID3 mFile = new UltraID3();
            FileInfo fInfo;
            mFile.Read(item);
            fInfo = new FileInfo(item);
            bool onDevice = true;
            if (DeviceMusic.Contains(item))
            {
                onDevice = false;
            }
            // My Problem starts here
            lstMusicInfo.Add(new MediaFile()
            {
                Title = mFile.Title,
                Album = mFile.Album,
                Year = mFile.Year.ToString(),
                ComDirectory = fInfo.Directory.FullName,
                FileFullName = fInfo.FullName,
                Artist = mFile.Artist,
                OnDevice = onDevice,
                PTDevice = false
            });
            //Ends here.
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }));
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lstViewMusicFiles.ItemsSource = lstMusicInfo;
        blkMusicStatus.Text = "";
        doneLoading = true;
    }));
    #endregion
}));
```

---

The first part of the code gives me almost instant result containing:

1. Address on computer of 5780 files.
2. Get list of all music files on an android device compare it with those 5780 files and return a list of files found on computer but not on device (in my case it returns a list with 5118 items).

---

The block of code below is my problem, I am filling data into a class, then adding that class into a `List<T>`, doing it for 5780 times takes 60 seconds, how can I improve it?

```
// My Problem starts here
lstMusicInfo.Add(new MediaFile
    {
        Title = mFile.Title,
        Album = mFile.Album,
        Year = mFile.Year.ToString(),
        ComDirectory = fInfo.Directory.FullName,
        FileFullName = fInfo.FullName,
        Artist = mFile.Artist,
        OnDevice = onDevice,
        PTDevice = false
    });
//Ends here.
```

**Update:**
Here is the profiling result and I see it's obvious why it's slowing down >_>
I suppose I should look for a different library that reads music file information.

[image]

Comment: Have you profiled the application?  Without a profile it's impossible to know why the operation is slow.  We could guess but it would be just that, a guess

Comment: @JaredPar Actually I haven't, I will do it right now and update my question with the results.

Comment: I agree with @JaredPar however, my gut tells me that reading the file info and the complete file attributes just takes a while. If you do that on 5000+ files, yes, it'll probably take a while and more so if you have a slow disk. You should probably run this on a background thread and update the UI asynchronously.

Comment: Do you have an SSD with incredibly low seek times or a legacy hard drive that physically has to move around to find the data?

Comment: @JaredPar I have updated my question with the result, and Kenneth was right, although I don't care about updating UI what I'm doing is process all files then show them to the user. Any alternatives I can use or do?

Comment: My point was that you don't need to show them all at once. The user can't process the info of 5000+ files at a time anyway. You should just read them one by one on a background thread and show them in the list as they become available. In this case, my gut (again) tells me you're just running into a hardware limitation.

Comment: @ta.speot.is nope, no SSD, and an HDD with 5400 RPM.

Comment: Also throwing `AsParallel` on everything when it's IO bound is not really a great idea. Reading ID3 doesn't involve reading a lot of data, most of the time will be spent seeking. Making your hard drive seek around a lot isn't the best idea. How are you synchronising access to `lstMusicInfo` in your `Parallel.ForEach(... lstMusicInfo.Add` ?

Comment: @Kenneth I will do as you recommended, thanks :)

Comment: @ta.speot.is ya I know, I mistakenly wrote "AsParallel" when retrieving data to LocalMusic list. I'm not synchronizing anything right now, I'm just testing my code. I know it's wrong because the output will come messed up and not organized but that was my 2nd step after fixing my first issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid loading everything once, up front, would be to lazy load the ID3 information as necessary.

You'd construct your `MediaFile` instances thus...

```
new MediaFile(filePath)
```

...and `MediaFile` would look something like the following.

```
internal sealed class MediaFile
{
    private readonly Lazy<UltraID3> _lazyFile;

    public MediaFile(string filePath)
    { 
        _lazyFile = new Lazy<UltraID3>(() =>
        {
            var file = new UltraID3();
            file.Read(filePath);
            return file;
        });
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _lazyFile.Value.Title; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is possibly less ideal than loading them as fast as you can in the background, if you do something like `MediaFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList()` and nothing has been lazy loaded then you'll have to wait for every file to load.

Loading them in the background would make them available for use immediately after the background loading has finished. But you might have to concern yourself with not accessing some items until the background loading has finished.

Comment: Thank you very much, that decreased loading time from 60 seconds to 20 seconds, now time to do what @Kenneth suggested, start showing one by one for the user.

Answer (score 2):

You biggest bottleneck is `new FileInfo(item)`, but you don't need `FileInfo` just to get the Directory and File names.  You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName` and `Path.GetFileName`, which are must faster since no I/O is involved.

```
                UltraID3 mFile = new UltraID3();
                //FileInfo fInfo;
                mFile.Read(item);
                //fInfo = new FileInfo(item);
                bool onDevice = true;
                if (DeviceMusic.Contains(item))
                {
                    onDevice = false;
                }
                // My Problem starts here
                lstMusicInfo.Add(new MediaFile()
                {
                    Title = mFile.Title,
                    Album = mFile.Album,
                    Year = mFile.Year.ToString(),
                    ComDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(item), // fInfo.Directory.FullName,
                    FileFullName = Path.GetFileName(item), //fInfo.FullName,
                    Artist = mFile.Artist,
                    OnDevice = onDevice,
                    PTDevice = false
                });
                //Ends here.
```

Comment: Yup that was my issue, I followed @ta.speot.is which made me remove the use of FileInfo and loading time was reduced to 20 seconds. Thank you for your answer :)